# AsyncTask doinBackground runtime error after moving function out of current class

Tags: android, class, android-asynctask, httpclient

I have a LoadImag class extends AsyncTask referenced from online resources. In the doinBackfround, it calls a function in the current class. everything works well, but when i move the function out of current class, it shows me runtime error function. I don't understand why.
here is my code:

This is the AsyncTask:

it's in the CLASS FragmentOne.java

```
public class loadMovieView extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "onPreExecute \n: preload bitmap in AsyncTask",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String...url) {
        // TODO 
        try{
            for(String strUrl: url){
                scrBitmap = decodeImg(strUrl,250,380);
                publishProgress(strUrl);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("img_decode", e.getMessage().toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String...arrUrl){
        Log.v("CurrentUrl", arrUrl.toString());
        horizontaLayout.addView(AddImagesToView(scrBitmap));
    }

}
```

And below this code is the function I used in the AsyncTask, decodeImg() and AddImagesToView(); because I need to use decodeImg() function a lot,

so I created a new class file called  ImageLoader.java

```
public class ImageLoader {
ImageLoader imgeLoader;

public Bitmap decodeImg(String path, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {
}

public Bitmap LoadImage(String url, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strUrl) throws IOException {
}
}
```

but now when i change the

```
scrBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(strUrl,250,380);
```

in the AsyncTask into

```
ImageLoader imgLoader;
scrBitmap = imgLoader.decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(strUrl,250,380);
```

it doesn't work now. the error log as below:

```
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): Process: com.example.theatre_sliding, PID: 19993
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing     doInBackground()
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at com.example.theatre_sliding.FragmentOne$loadMovieView.doInBackground(FragmentOne.java:128)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at com.example.theatre_sliding.FragmentOne$loadMovieView.doInBackground(FragmentOne.java:1)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-03 11:12:03.462: E/AndroidRuntime(19993): ... 4 more
```

I have no idea why is it, can anyone help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: This is not an answer, but look into using a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for asynchronously loading and caching images.  It will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just need to use this as part of my app's function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized your object properly. So this code should be:

```
ImageLoader imgLoader;
```

Something like this:

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader();
```

Comment: oh....I'm so stupid, I can't believe that I forgot this !!!! problem solved!! thanks!!